# How to assign a scope to a sublime text 3 context menu?

Tags: sublimetext3, contextmenu

I added a right click context menu to sublime text 3 by creating a `Context.sublime-menu` file in `Packages/user` folder with the following configuration:

```
[
    {
        "caption": "wrap with try",
        "mnemonic": "t",
        "id": "try",
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args": { "name": "Packages/User/js-try.sublime-snippet" }
    }
]
```

This works fine. But I want it to appear only when the current file is a javascript file, just like you can assign a scope to a snippet by configuring `<scope>source.js</scope>`. I did not find any documentation on this on the one hand, on the other hand I see that there are context menu's that are behaving this way, so I know its possible.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Menu item visibility is controlled by the command being referenced. See the `is_visible` method at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.TextCommand.

As the built in `insert_snippet` command always returns `True` for this method, to achieve this, you will need to write a (small) custom plugin which will act as a wrapper for your desired command:

- From the Tools menu -> Developer -> New Plugin...
- Replace the template with:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ProxyCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, command_name, scope_selector, **kwargs):
        self.view.run_command(command_name, kwargs)

    def is_visible(self, command_name, scope_selector, **kwargs):
        return self.view.match_selector(self.view.sel()[0].begin(), scope_selector)
```

- save it, in the User package, as something like `proxy_command.py` - the base filename doesn't matter, only the extension matters
- now, change your context menu entry to: (note that we are now asking the menu entry to point to the `proxy` command we just created, and passing in arguments to tell it which scope (selector) it should be active for, and which real command to execute and with what arguments.)

```
[
    {
        "caption": "wrap with try",
        "mnemonic": "t",
        "id": "try",
        "command": "proxy",
        "args": {
            "command_name": "insert_snippet",
            "name": "Packages/User/js-try.sublime-snippet",
            "scope_selector": "source.js",
        },
    }
]
```

You could take this a step further and build a general purpose snippet wrapper command, which could read the snippet file (using the `sublime.load_resource` API and then parse the XML) to see if the `<scope>` specified there matches, rather than requiring it to be entered(/potentially duplicated) in the context menu entry.